# Codeigniter switch language with url

Tags: codeigniter

I have built it all: I mean switching languages with hooks works, but now I want to get language from the url and switch it then, like:

http://localhost/about-me

or

http://localhost/o-meni

So if I send first link to someone it should automatically detect language and display that page and all navigation links in that language.

In the routes I have already forwarded to my main controller's function param which language I want to use. Now I need to set that language. But if I do $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', "српски") language in behind doesn't change for everything.

I have noticed that, that in existing language switcher, redirection is used after setting language session to selected language, redirect to referral link, but now how to manage direct user input?

I hope I made myself clear and hope someone will get into this.

Thank you.

Comment: dont quite understand what you want - usually multilingual pages do have a structure like `http://localhost/en/about-me` where the first `uri segment` is always the language - in your case its quite hard to understand how you did that - pls show some code - because without a code fragement i've a hard time to understand what you really want...

Comment: Please take your answer out of the question and create a self-answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, which is encouraged by Stack Overflow. That way you create a clear Q/A pair, which will be useful for future readers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution like this:

**Update 1:**

I did it like this, first in language switcher:

```
class LanguageSwitcher extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function switchLang($language = "") {
    $lang_en['about-me'] = 'o-meni';
    $lang_sr['o-meni'] = 'about-me';

    $lang_en['services'] = 'usluge';
    $lang_sr['usluge'] = 'services';

    $lang_en['products'] = 'proizvodi';
    $lang_sr['proizvodi'] = 'products';

    $lang_en['downloads'] = 'preuzimanja';
    $lang_sr['preuzimanja'] = 'downloads';

    $lang_en['contact'] = 'kontakt';
    $lang_sr['kontakt'] = 'contact';

    if ($language === "") {
      $language = 'српски';
    }

    $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);

    $referrer = strtolower($this->agent->referrer());
    //log_message('error', "switchLang:" . $referrer . ", lang:" . $language);
    if ($referrer !== "") {
      $l = str_replace(base_url(), "", substr($referrer, strrpos($referrer, base_url())));

      if (urldecode($language) === 'српски' && array_key_exists($l, $lang_en)) {
        $referrer = str_replace($l, $lang_en[$l], $referrer);
      } else
      if (urldecode($language) === 'english' && array_key_exists($l, $lang_sr)) {
        $referrer = str_replace($l, $lang_sr[$l], $referrer);
      }

      redirect($referrer);
    }
  }

}
```

and secondly in my controller, create a function to call:

```
private function redirectLanguage($param) {
  $site_lang = urldecode($this->session->userdata('site_lang'));
  //echo $param . "+" . $site_lang;
  if ($param === "sr" && ($site_lang === "english" || $site_lang === "")) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', "српски");
    $this->lang->load("message", "српски");
  } else if ($param === "en" && ($site_lang === "српски" || $site_lang === "")) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', "english");
    $this->lang->load("message", "english");
  }
}
```

like this:

```
  public function about($param = "") {

    $this->redirectLanguage($param);

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('main_starts');
    $this->load->view('about-me');
    $this->load->view('main_ends');
    $this->load->view('footer');
  }
```

this way I can catch it if directly pasted to the browser address bar and load the messages and set session site_lang.

Now it works, all except some issues in IE and EDGE;

**Update 2:**

I had to add this to make sure it will work in other browsers too:

```
$browser = $this->agent->browser();

if ($browser === "Chrome" || $browser === "Firefox") {
  header("Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public");
} else {
  header("Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT");
  header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
}
```

because sessions won't work well in internet explorer if caching is turned on so better turn it off.